# Controller - init not calls on windows back button transist

Tags: ember.js

I require to set some default on the `controller` init method. on back button transits I am not getting the controller `init` method called. how can i insist the call?

here is my controller init method:

```
init() {

        this._super(...arguments);

//but not calling.
        Ember.run.schedule("afterRender",this,function() {
          console.log("afterRender");
        });

    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controller are singletons, so the `init` function will only be called once (first time the controller is needed).

You could use the `setupController` function do set some defaults:

```
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';

export default Route.extend({
    setupController(controller, model) {
        this._super(...arguments);

        //setup controller will be called every time the model refreshes
        controller.set('foo', 'bar');
    }
});
```